# Mongo connector with neo4j not working

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I'm running the following command:

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
```

But getting following error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "mongo_connector.util"<br/>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())<br/>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 85, in wrapped<br/>
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-<br/>packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 1041, in main
    conf.parse_args()<br/>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/config.py", line 118, in parse_args
    option, dict((k, values.get(k)) for k in option.cli_names))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 824, in apply_doc_managers
    module = import_dm_by_name(dm['docManager'])<br/>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 814, in import_dm_by_name
    "vailable doc managers." % full_name)
mongo_connector.errors.InvalidConfiguration: Could not import mongo_connector.doc_managers.neo4j_doc_manager. It could be that this doc manager has been moved out of this project and is maintained elsewhere. Make sure that you have the doc manager installed alongside mongo-connector. Check the README for a list of available doc managers.
```

**NOTE:** I'm using neo4j 3.0, os: macosx, python: 2.7**

Comment: I know that's not the point of the question, but if you are using Mongo with Neo4j I'd really recommend you to check: http://orientdb.com/orientdb/. It's the best of the 2 worlds in a single and easy-to-use DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an error caused by failing to pin the py2neo dependency to a specific version. This project was written using py2neo 2.0.7 but failed to pin that version, as py2neo 3.0 is  now being pulled in a few things are breaking.

We will push an update for 3.0 soon, in the meantime you can get around this by uninstalling py2neo and installing version 2.0.7:

```
lyonwj@lyonwjs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~/n/mongo_demo> pip uninstall py2neo
Uninstalling py2neo-3
...
lyonwj@lyonwjs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~/n/mongo_demo> pip install py2neo==2.0.7
Collecting py2neo==2.0.7
  Downloading py2neo-2.0.7.tar.gz (251kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 2.6MB/s
Installing collected packages: py2neo
  Running setup.py install for py2neo ... done
Successfully installed py2neo-2.0.7
lyonwj@lyonwjs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~/n/mongo_demo>
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
Logging to mongo-connector.log.
```

See https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager/issues/60