# Is Neo4j Doc Manager still functional?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, persistence

I have to do an assignment with multiple databases, and I was thinking in polyglot persistence between MongoDB an Neo4j. I have seen some of the documentation for the [Neo4j doc manager](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager), and the last time it was updated was in 2016, and it has a build fail on github. I still tried to use it, but then I had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393777/mongo-connector-with-neo4j-not-working) and could not install py2neo 2.0.7.
Is there a solution for this, or should i give up on Neo4j doc manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j Doc Manager is discontinued as the last commit was 5 years ago.
You can use any APOC mongoDB procedure that are available at https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.mongodb/. In any case, you will have to develop your own ETL tool, perhaps with Apache Hop or Talend.